# iphone image loading problem

Tags: iphone

I have make a one small image and in which one detail page is there. 
and I in detail page I have one image tag which is in `webview` with html page.
It's work completely but image take a much time for loading and show in the screen.
So how can I reduce the time of loading for image. and this image is come form url.

Comment: you forget to post some code in your question.. help us is help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imgBiteSpot.clipsToBounds=YES; 
    NSData *imageData = [[[NSData alloc]init]autorelease];
    imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ObjBitSpot.StrImagePath]];
    if(imageData==0)
    {
        imgBiteSpot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img-not-found.gif"];
    }
    else {
        UIImage *imgs = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(88,88));
        [imgs drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 88.0, 88.0)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        imgBiteSpot.image=newImage;
        [imgs release];
    }
```

Comment: please give time to format your answer .. also you can edit your answer and add more info if you want you don't need to add another answer

Answer (score 1):

You could consider not downloading the image but downloading a one characters variable/flag from a web service. Depending on the answer from the web service you could load an image locally from the bundle? This could be faster.

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

This is best example for loading image.

http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2009/11/remote-image-for-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Its take time base on image size and internet speed.

But one thing you can do in your application.

You can download asynchronously that image and store it in temporary variable before you go in detail image view. When you go on that detail image you can load that downloaded image as per your requirement.